Best way to create a data structure (class) that can contain only constant value
I'm creating a videogame and in this video game there are different classes. Every class has the same data structure of every other class but different values. For example a class has 3 element: class name, starting health points and class picture path.
Which is the best practice to do something like this?
My best guess is to create a class and then create an instance for every ingame-class with the corresponding value
Explanatory example:
public class InGameClass {
    public string className;
    public int startingHP;
    public string picturePath;

    public InGameClass(string newClassName, int newStartingHP, string newPicturePath) {
        className = newClassName;
        startingHP = newStartingHP;
        picturePath = newPicturePath;
    }
}

And then I create a class that got all the instantiated class
public class InGameClasses {
    public InGameClass Mage = new InGameClass("Mage", 90, "Resources/Class/Mage");
    public InGameClass Warrior= new InGameClass("Warrior", 100, "Resources/Class/Warrior");
}


I would firstly recommend to not call any conceptual entity in your project "a class". "Class" in C# has a very specific meaning and overriding it with anything else can never not introduce confusion.

Instead of storing the class names, you can derive classes with this name and then you can compare the class types instead of their names as strings.
public abstract class Character
{
    public abstract int StartingHP { get; }
    public abstract string PicturePath { get; }
}

public class Mage : Character
{
    public override int StartingHP => 90;
    public override string PicturePath => "Resources/Class/Mage"; 
}

public class Warrior : Character
{
    public override int StartingHP => 100;
    public override string PicturePath => "Resources/Class/Warrior"; 

    public void Attack(Character other); // Method specific to warriors.
    {
        ...
    }
}

Note that I made the base class abstract. This means that you cannot write new Character(); however, you can, e.g., create a list of Characters containing Mages and Warriors.
The deriving classes are forced to override the inherited abstract members and to provide a concrete implementation.
List<Character> characters = new();
characters.Add(new Mage());
characters.Add(new Warrior());

You can test the type of character like this:
if (character is Warrior warrior) {
    warrior.Attack(someCharacter);
}

Put methods for things all characters can do in the base class. E.g., public virtual void Walk() { ... }. Making it virtual allows you to override it in a descendant class, e.g. if a character walks in a different way than others. Different characters will behave differently automatically (see: Polymorphism).
An advantage of this approach  (class hierarchy) is that you can implement different behaviors for different characters very easily.
See also:

Inheritance - derive types to create more specialized behavior.
Tutorial - Inheritance in C# and .NET.
Polymorphism.
Properties (C# Programming Guide).


Alternatives (in response to a comment):
You can use constants which are static by default or static readonly fields or getter-only properties. The problem, however, is that static members cannot be inherited. You could also use a Singleton, which combines the static access with the possibility to define a class hierarchy.
You could also use getter-only properties implementing a Static abstract interface. This is the most advanced technique. It allows you to add "constants" (implemented as static getter-only properties) to every concrete Character class in a structured way, i.e., by enforcing a specific and well-defined set of properties.
You could also store a constants structure in a dictionary by Character type.
The Abstract factory pattern may also be useful.

Thank you for your answer. The children of the Character class should be a data structure that contains constant values, because those are immutable values that apply to every character that is for example a Mage or a Warrior. Is there a way to make this classes immutable or constant?
To explain it better: can I make something similar to a readonly JSON that contains all the general info for an ingame class?

So I can just get the info without instantiating a new object for every new character

A nice way to do this is with a private constructer and static  values as your "constants"
public class InGameClass 
{
    public string ClassName {get; private set; }
    public int StartingHP {get; private set; }
    public string PicturePath {get; private set; }

    private InGameClass(string newClassName, int newStartingHP, string newPicturePath) {
        ClassName = newClassName;
        StartingHP = newStartingHP;
        PicturePath = newPicturePath;
    }
    public static readonly InGameClass Mage;
    public static readonly InGameClass Warrior;

    static InGameClass()
    {
        Mage = new InGameClass("Mage", 90, "Resources/Class/Mage");
        Warrior= new InGameClass("Warrior", 100, "Resources/Class/Warrior");
    }
}

Here, we leave the constructor private so no more objects can be constructed and we use a static constructor to create the values required and store them in static readonly fields.
Now you can use in your code InGameClass.Mage or InGameClass.Warrior.
This pattern is usally called Type-Safe Enums.
